# How to determine row of an AND function Excel

Tags: excel, lookup

I am trying to determine which row of my spreadsheet an AND function returns True for.

For example, I have a column which contains a String category number called Route. 
I then have the route broken up into sections. I want to find the specific information If i know a route ID and a specific mile point. As such I need

```
If(AND(route=specified.route, Beginning.marker <= specified.marker, specified.marker <= end.marker), Return.Row, "not found")
```

I can then use this to acquire the other information about this specific segment in the spread sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MATCH() Function.

For this purpose let us assume the following:

- route is Column A
- Beginning is Column B
- End is Column C

The Formula would be:

```
=MATCH(1,IF(($A$1:$A$1000 = specified.route)*($B$1:$B$1000 <= specified.marker)*($C$1:$C$1000 >= specified.marker),1,0),0)
```

This is an array formula.  Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode. When done correctly Excel will automatically put `{}` around the formula to denote an array formula.

Array formulas do not like the use of `And` and `Or` in their calculations so we replace them with the mathematical operands `*` and `+` respectively.  This works because the criteria will return TRUE/FALSE which are stored as a Boolean that are essentially 1/0, respectively.

Array Formulas should not use full column references as the computations are exponential and will slow down the calculation times.  So keep the range references as small as can be while covering the greatest number of rows the data could conceivably be.

---

Now, I am assuming here that you want to use the row number to find a value in another column, to return that value you wrap the whole thing in an INDEX() function.

So lets assume you want the value from Column D where the Criteria is True:

```
=INDEX(D$1:$D$1000,MATCH(1,IF(($A$1:$A$1000 = specified.route)*($B$1:$B$1000 <= specified.marker)*($C$1:$C$1000 >= specified.marker),1,0),0))
```

This also is an Array Formula.  Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode. When done correctly Excel will automatically put `{}` around the formula to denote an array formula.

---

So now what to do with the ones that do not result in a row number because one or more of the three criterion is always false.  Wrap the whole in an IFERROR() Function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:$D$1000,MATCH(1,IF(($A$1:$A$1000 = specified.route)*($B$1:$B$1000 <= specified.marker)*($C$1:$C$1000 >= specified.marker),1,0),0)),"not found")
```

Again this is an array formula so the above conditions apply.

This will return `"not found"` if there is no match.

Comment: Thank you for your response Scott! Was very clear and helpful. It also worked perfectly!